# Very Slow Apache httpserver response (httpcore 4.3.2 libs)

Tags: java, apache, netbeans

I am using httpcore libraries 4.3.2 to make a custom http server to communicate with some clients (android devices).

The clients manage to communicate (post an xml) with the server but the response of the server is very slow.

My code is based on the ElementalHttpServer of apache samples. Can i find somewhere else better samples for the httpcore libraries? 
Also i can not find how to set the parameteres or to finetune the httpserver because the HttParams lib is deprecated.

If i use the com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer httpserver my clients are connecting without problem. It is better to stay with suns libs or to use apaches?

Thanks in advance.

This is the code i used:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InterruptedIOException;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLServerSocketFactory;
import org.apache.http.ConnectionClosedException;
import org.apache.http.HttpConnectionFactory;
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpEntityEnclosingRequest;
import org.apache.http.HttpException;
import org.apache.http.HttpRequest;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.HttpServerConnection;
import org.apache.http.HttpStatus;
import org.apache.http.entity.ContentType;
import org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity;
import org.apache.http.impl.DefaultBHttpServerConnection;
import org.apache.http.impl.DefaultBHttpServerConnectionFactory;
import org.apache.http.protocol.BasicHttpContext;
import org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext;
import org.apache.http.protocol.HttpProcessor;
import org.apache.http.protocol.HttpProcessorBuilder;
import org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestHandler;
import org.apache.http.protocol.HttpService;
import org.apache.http.protocol.ResponseConnControl;
import org.apache.http.protocol.ResponseContent;
import org.apache.http.protocol.ResponseDate;
import org.apache.http.protocol.ResponseServer;
import org.apache.http.protocol.UriHttpRequestHandlerMapper;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;

public class Thread_Main_httpcore2 implements Runnable {

    public Thread_Main_httpcore2() {

    }//Thread_Main()

    @Override
    public void run() {
        int port = 20010;

        // Set up the HTTP protocol processor
        HttpProcessor httpproc = HttpProcessorBuilder.create()
                .add(new ResponseDate())
                .add(new ResponseServer("Test/1.1"))
                .add(new ResponseContent())
                .add(new ResponseConnControl()).build();

        // Set up request handlers
        UriHttpRequestHandlerMapper reqistry = new UriHttpRequestHandlerMapper();

        //// Set up the HTTP service
        HttpService httpService = new HttpService(httpproc, reqistry);

        reqistry.register("*", new Thread_Main_httpcore2.HttpReqHandler());

        SSLServerSocketFactory sf = null;

        try {
            Thread t = new RequestListenerThread(port, httpService, sf);
            t.setDaemon(false);
            t.start();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    static class HttpReqHandler implements HttpRequestHandler {

        public HttpReqHandler() {
            super();
        }

        public void handle(
                final HttpRequest request,
                final HttpResponse response,
                final HttpContext context) throws HttpException, IOException {

                String xml_stream="";


            if (request instanceof HttpEntityEnclosingRequest) {
                HttpEntity entity = ((HttpEntityEnclosingRequest) request).getEntity();
                byte[] entityContent;
                if (entity == null) {
                    entityContent = new byte[0];
                } else {
                    entityContent = EntityUtils.toByteArray(entity);
                }

                //byte[] entityContent = EntityUtils.toByteArray(entity);
                System.out.println("Incoming entity content (bytes): " + entityContent.length);

                xml_stream = new String(entityContent);
            }

            StringBuilder resp_xml = new StringBuilder();
                resp_xml.append("Returns an xml to the client");

            StringEntity entity;
            try {
                response.setStatusCode(HttpStatus.SC_OK);
                entity = new StringEntity(resp_xml.toString(), ContentType.create("text/html", "UTF-8"));
                response.setEntity(entity);

            } catch (Exception ex_send_resp) {
                System.out.println("HttpFileHandler.ex_send_resp "+ ex_send_resp.toString());
            }

        }

    }

    static class RequestListenerThread extends Thread {

        private final HttpConnectionFactory<DefaultBHttpServerConnection> connFactory;
        private final ServerSocket serversocket;
        private final HttpService httpService;

        public RequestListenerThread(
                final int port,
                final HttpService httpService,
                final SSLServerSocketFactory sf) throws IOException {
            this.connFactory = DefaultBHttpServerConnectionFactory.INSTANCE;
            this.serversocket = sf != null ? sf.createServerSocket(port) : new ServerSocket(port);
            this.httpService = httpService;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("Listening on port " + this.serversocket.getLocalPort());
            while (!Thread.interrupted()) {
                try {
                    // Set up HTTP connection
                    Socket socket = this.serversocket.accept();
                    System.out.println("Incoming connection from " + socket.getInetAddress());
                    HttpServerConnection conn = this.connFactory.createConnection(socket);

                    // Start worker thread
                    Thread t = new WorkerThread(this.httpService, conn);
                    t.setDaemon(true);
                    t.start();
                } catch (InterruptedIOException ex) {
                    break;
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    System.err.println("I/O error initialising connection thread: "
                            + e.getMessage());
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    static class WorkerThread extends Thread {

        private final HttpService httpservice;
        private final HttpServerConnection conn;

        public WorkerThread(
                final HttpService httpservice,
                final HttpServerConnection conn) {
            super();
            this.httpservice = httpservice;
            this.conn = conn;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("New connection thread");
            HttpContext context = new BasicHttpContext(null);
            try {
                while (!Thread.interrupted() && this.conn.isOpen()) {
                    this.httpservice.handleRequest(this.conn, context);
                }
            } catch (ConnectionClosedException ex) {
                System.err.println("Client closed connection");
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                System.err.println("I/O error: " + ex.getMessage());
            } catch (HttpException ex) {
                System.err.println("Unrecoverable HTTP protocol violation: " + ex.getMessage());
            } finally {
                try {
                    this.conn.shutdown();
                } catch (IOException ignore) {
                }
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Why don\t you use an embeddable webserver like jetty or undertow?

Comment: I send some custom headers and i do not know if jetty or undertow supports it.

Comment: Also i am using netbeans and jetty is for eclipse only.

Comment: What do you mean jetty is for eclipse only? And most servers support custom headers. You might also want to look into Ratpack http://www.ratpack.io/

Comment: If you search for jetty project or view their web site. You will see that it is for eclipse. You may use it under netbeans via Maven but a lot of users report problems. Also i do not know Groovy. I am using the httpserver at the local network only for collecting data from the clients.  I found jetty very helpfull but it is very hard to embed it in netbeans (or hard for me).

Comment: With embed in Netbeans you mean a Netbeans plugin, or just developing in Netbeans. And for Ratpack you don't need groovy, just scroll further down for the Java Code.